# XNA game : calculate time between two shoots

Tags: time, xna

I'm trying to make a game with the XNA library.  I want a sprite to throw a fireball to hit falling asteroids.  But I have a problem with pressing the concrete key: I want to throw fireballs, for example, with one second between throws.

I want to measure the time difference between creating instances.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UYou can use the [ElapsedGameTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.gametime.elapsedgametime.aspx) property of the `gameTime` variable passed to the `Update` method like this:

```
const float shootTimer = 1.0f;
float elapsedTime = 0f;

protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)   
{   
    // Allows the game to exit   
    if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)   
        this.Exit();   

    elapsedTime += gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;  

    if(elapsedTime >= shootTimer && /* Your logic to see if you should shoot a fireball */ )
    {
        // Shoot the fireball!
        elapsedTime = 0f;
    }

    base.Update(gameTime);   
}
```

Basically, what you are doing in the above code is setting a minimum value (seconds) that need to pass between each shot.
Then you create a variable that will store the amount of time that has passed between each shot.

In the `Update` method, you add the time between each `Update` call and then check if it is bigger than the timer, and if it is, then you shoot and reset the elapsed time.

**Note:** I wrote that piece of code out of the top of my mind so it may have some minor issue.

Answer (score 0):

Each call to `Update` of your main `Game` class or any `GameComponent` receives an instance of `GameTime` as an argument.  Its property [`ElapsedGameTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.gametime.elapsedgametime.aspx) can be used to accumulate the passage of time.